# how to save keyboard layouts per-app (windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout

At the moment, windows keeps my keyboard layouts per window. When I close a window and open it back up again, it loses the old keyboard layouts. As I only want to use qwerty in games, it would be much simpler if I could simply keep the layout on a per-app basis. For examle, it would be nice if I could set it so that whenever I open chrome, it opens in dvorak, but whenever I open some game, it opens in qwerty.

Comment: If there's no better solution an AutoHotkey script that switches keyboard layout based on which app is currently active should help.

Comment: Actually, that looks exactly like what I'm looking for. I'll try it out.